# wp_kses() strips data attributes even if it's in the allowed list

Tags: wp-kses

I added a function that will return the allowed html tags array

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'allowed_html_tags' ) ) {
  /**
   * Allowed html tags for wp_kses() function
   *
   * @return array Array of allowed html tags.
   */
  function allowed_html_tags() {
    return array(
      'a' => array(
        'href' => array(),
        'title' => array(),
        'class' => array(),
        'data' => array(),
        'rel'   => array(),
      ),
      'br' => array(),
      'em' => array(),
      'ul' => array(
          'class' => array(),
      ),
      'ol' => array(
          'class' => array(),
      ),
      'li' => array(
          'class' => array(),
      ),
      'strong' => array(),
      'div' => array(
        'class' => array(),
        'data' => array(),
        'style' => array(),
      ),
      'span' => array(
        'class' => array(),
        'style' => array(),
      ),
      'img' => array(
          'alt'    => array(),
          'class'  => array(),
          'height' => array(),
          'src'    => array(),
          'width'  => array(),
      ),
      'select' => array(
          'id'   => array(),
          'class' => array(),
          'name' => array(),
      ),
      'option' => array(
          'value' => array(),
          'selected' => array(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But when I have html in a variable that is populated in a `foreach` loop, my `data` attributes get stripped out.

```
$my_var = '<div class="my-class" data-term="$term_id">$content</div>';

wp_kses( $my_var, allowed_html_tags() );
```

This will return

```
<div class="my-class">This is my content... no data attribute...</div>
```

I tried modifying my array to have `data-*` but that didn't work.

I hope that you don't have to modify the allowed array with the full data name (`data-term`) for this to work...

#### EDIT

Check [Matt Thomason's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/324922/58895) answer about the update to the kses data.

Comment: dingo_d please update selected answer to reflect new information added by Matt Thomason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I hope that you don't have to modify the allowed array with the full data name (data-term) for this to work...

It appears to be that way. `data-term` and `data` aren't the same attribute after all, and poking around in core I don't think any sort of regular expressions can be used as supported attributes.

You shouldn't need to run `wp_kses()` on your own markup though, you should know it's safe. `wp_kses()` is generally just for handling untrusted input from users. Are users going to be submitting data- attributes, and you need to support them all?

You could do something like this instead:

```
$my_var = '<div class="my-class" data-term="' . esc_attr( $term_id ) . '">' . wp_kses_post( $content ) . '</div>';
```

That uses `wp_kses_post()` which will use the default allowed html for posts, but it's only going to apply to whatever `$content` is.

Comment: I did escape it prior, but I'd like to escape it on the output as well. I guess I'll just put a comment to silence the phpcs. Thanks

Comment: `You shouldn't need to run wp_kses() on your own markup though` unfortunately if you apply for a plugin review in 2024, the review team insists on doing exactly so.

Answer (score 12):

Update for anyone coming here post-Dec 2018:

data-* is now supported in KSES filters, since this commit - https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress/commit/a0309e80b6a4d805e4f230649be07b4bfb1a56a5#diff-a0e0d196dd71dde453474b0f791828fe

So you can now do something like this:

```
add_filter('wp_kses_allowed_html', "kses_filter_allowed_html"));

function kses_filter_allowed_html( $allowed, $context )
{
    if (is_array($context))
    {
        return $allowed;
    }

    if ($context === 'post')
    {
        $allowed['a']['data-*'] = true;
        $allowed['table']['data-*'] = true; 
        // ... keep on doing these for each HTML entity you want to allow data- attributes on
    }

    return $allowed;
}
```